# elasticsearch "smart or" operator

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I have next indexed docs:

`[
  {
    id: 1
    title: "Programming languages - Java",
  },
  {
    id: 2
    title: "Programming languages - Python",
  },
  {
    id: 3
    title: "Program languages - Lisp",
  }
]`

A user who is looking for documents about java and python, likely to make a request like this: books about programming java and python. 
Can I build a query to return only the documents 1 and 2?

The problem is that if combine the terms through the operator AND, nothing will be found. At the same time, when using the operator OR, will return all the documents, but in this case the document with id 3 is redundant.

Also need to consider that in the query can contain extra terms which are not exist in the documents such as books and the word "and".

Answer (score 0):

A simple [match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) query might already fit your needs:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "books about programming java and python",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```